# App doesn't launch after adding a method (Xcode 7.2)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm new to Cocoa and Mac programming so sorry if this is a bad question,but I got frustrated and I don't know what to do. Heres my ViewController files (Appdelegate.h and .m is left untouched to default)[image]

Up to this point everything works as expected, App compiles and runs without a problem. but when I start adding some logic to a method `updateDetailViews` I get this:
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Turn off the breakpoint?

Comment: Grab that blue thing in the margin on line 83 and drag it away to the left.  It will vanish in a puff.  Then re-run your app or click the play button on the toolbar below your code.

Comment: @i_am_jorf thanks it worked

Answer (score 2):

You can run your application removing the blue arrow. (Use drag and drop to remove).
It is use to check your function is called or not while your application is running. So when it call your application stop running and show this line. You can run again using the play type button from console.